# How do I fix CSS style border around the anchor element?

Tags: html, css

This a simple sign up formed I've made my school project and for one to sign up is to choose their roles. There's not much to this but I can't seem to figure how to fix this border problem under the anchor? How do I make it so that the space at the top is equivalent to the bottom as well?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKrbr.png)

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 99%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 15px;
}

a {
  background-color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block inline;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1.5;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>WELCOME TO SMK USJ 12<br/> ENGLISH QUIZ</h2>
  </div>
  <form action="role.php" method="post">
    <div class="box">
      <h3>Choose your role<br/> You are a...</h3>
      <a href="teacher.php">Teacher</a></button>
      <a href="student.php">Student</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `</button>` with no corresponding opening element? You also forgot to close your form tag

Comment: Apart from the above issues you could just increase the padding for box div to 25px `.box {
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:30%;
    padding:25px;
}`

Comment: @j08691 ah im sorry im new to this i completely looked past that thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @BikkiMahato ive tried that but its still not in the center of the box which is bothering me

Comment: @ronnie Did you try using CSS Flexbox? You can refer from here [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: @BikkiMahato I'll try referring to that then,, thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo with the `display` property on the `a` tags. I think you meant to use `inline-block` instead of `block inline`?

```
a {
  /* ... */
  display: inline-block;
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution (in my opinion) would be to change your markup a bit, employ a wrapping container for the buttons and then apply the proper styles to that container. However, without changing your markup - you can still achieve what you are looking for, by adding some `line-height` to your buttons. Something like:

```
.box a{
 line-height: 5em;
}
```

Should put you in the ball-park of what you are trying to achieve.